# What is the probability of two dice getting a sum of 7 without a two?

Tags: probability, dice

I am currently working on conditional probability and I am somewhat confused about how exactly to complete this problem. I know that to find conditional probability that you utilize:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

I also know that there is a $6/36$ chance to roll a sum of 7, and that if you roll a sum of 7 that there is a $4/6$ chance to get a sum without using the number 2. I do not know what else is necessary however in order to finish this problem and to find $P(A|B)$.

Comment: Why does it have to be conditional?  $7=6+1=1+6=3+4=4+3$  How many are there?

Comment: What do think A and B should be - what events?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $1/9$?  I'm reading it as you can roll a seven using two fair die including 2's, you just are not looking for specifically 5+2 or 2+5 as part of your event.

Comment: @ampage, can you be a little more specific as to what you are looking for?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven The question asks "A pair of dice are rolled. What is the probability that neither die shows a 2 given that they sum to 7? What is the probability that they sum to 7 given that neither die shows a 2?" It seems to me that the answer would be the same, however, I'm not sure why it would be asked inversely if that were the case.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what you wrote in the title.  In fact, it never says "given" any where in your title.  "What ist he probability of two dice getting a sum of 7 without a 2" is a deviation from the question you have above.   It just seemed unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B= \{1,3,4,5,6\}^2$.

$A= \{ (i,j) | i+j = 7, i, j \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \}$.

Answer (score 0):

The Event $E$of rolling two dice that sum to seven not including a sum with summand 2 would be 
$$\{(1,6),(3,4),(4,3),(6,1)\}$$

Thus $|E|=4$.
Since the sample space has cardinality $36$, $P(E)=4/36=1/9$.

Answer (score 0):

> I also know that there is a 6/36 chance to roll a sum of 7, and that if you 
>   roll 
>   a sum of 7 that there is a 4/6 chance to get a sum without using the number 2.

So, putting these statements into probability notation, you have,
$$
\begin{split}
P(x_1 + x_2 = 7) &= \frac{6}{36}\\
P(x_1\ne 2 \cap x_2 \ne 2 | x_1 + x_2 = 7) &= \:\frac{4}{6}
\end{split}
$$
So, what you want is $P(x_1 \ne 2 \cap x_2\ne 2  \cap x_1 + x_2 = 7)$ (*i.e.* the joint probability), so using the conditional probability definition:
$$
P(x_1\ne 2 \cap x_2 \ne 2 | x_1 + x_2 = 7) 
= \frac{P(x_1 \ne 2 \cap x_2\ne 2 \cap x_1 + x_2 = 7)}{P(x_1 + x_2 = 7)} 
\qquad
$$
and thus, 
$$
P(x_1 \ne 2 \cap x_2\ne 2 \cap x_1 + x_2 = 7) = P(x_1\ne 2 \cap x_2 \ne 2 | x_1 + x_2 = 7){P(x_1 + x_2 = 7)}.
$$