# Rolling a pair of dice, conditional probability of neither die showing a 2 given they sum to 7.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

This question is identical to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265380/what-is-the-probability-of-two-dice-getting-a-sum-of-7-without-a-two), but I am not finding the explanation I am looking for in that question.

My sample space would be $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$ and $P(s) = \frac{1}{36}$ for all $s \in S$.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to solve this problem using the formula $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$, but I can't get the answer to make sense. I want to solve it using this formula.

Let A be the event that neither die shows a 2. So $A = \{1,3,4,5,6\}^2$ and $|A| = 25$. $P(A) = \frac{25}{36}$.

Let $B$ be the event that the two dice sum up to $7$. So $B = \{(1,6), (6,1), (4,3), (3,4), (2,5), (5,2)\}$ $|B| = 6$ and $P(B) = \frac{1}{6}$.

Then $A \cap B = \{(1,6), (6,1), (4,3), (3,4)\}$, $|A \cap B| = 4$, and $P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{9}$.

Using the above formula, you get that $P(A|B) = \frac{3}{2}$, which is obviously not correct.

I am having a lot of trouble solving anything with this formula, so I'd appreciate an explanation using only that formula if possible - I know there are other ways of thinking about the problem from the other post.

I then need to do the reverse of the statement, "What is the probability the dice sum to 7, given that neither die shows a 2?" which will be difficult when I'm not understanding the first example.

Comment: You got the probabilities right, but at the end you are doing the fraction arithmetic wrong. What is $1/9$ divided by $1/6$?

Comment: $\frac{2}{3}$ My bad on that one, ha!...but I was expecting my answer to be $\frac{1}{9}$. Why is it different than in the linked question?

Comment: The questions are related but not identical.  That one asks for the probability  of $A\cap B$, which you found along the way.

Comment: The answer shown there is 2/3 also (they say 4/6), except for the last answer which is obviously wrong - it computes the unconditional probability, out of the full sample space - not CONDITIONAL on the sum being seven.

Comment: I found my answer for the reverse of the question to be $P(B|A) = \frac{4}{25}$. If that's correct, I am feeling more comfortable and understand the difference here.

Answer (score 1):

community wiki answer so that the question can be closed

You correctly found that
\begin{align*}
P(A) & = \frac{25}{36}\\
P(B) & = \frac{1}{6}\\
P(A \cap B) & = \frac{1}{9}
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{6}} = \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{6}{1} = \frac{2}{3}$$
rather than $3/2$ as you initially calculated.